# ¿Cómo usar el cuerpo de una función importada desde un fichero a otro?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy tratando de usar una función que tengo en un fichero para tratar de rehusar mi código y no ser repetitivo, el punto es que tengo esta función:

```
 def archivo():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Comunidad" : "Trabajadores",
        "Persona":Personas,
        "Enlace":enlaces,
        "Descripción" : descripciones
    })
    df.to_excel('trabajadores.xlsx', index=False)
```

Cómo puedo hacer para usar esta misma función con los mismos datos pero cambiar el nombre del archivo y el nombre del valor del diccionario de comunidad. Ya la importé, hice el from archivo1 import archivo, lo que quiero es editarla

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/guia-de-funciones-de-python-con-ejemplos/) que habla de funciones en python. En general, te hace falta declarar tus argumentos. Saludos

Comment: Pasa el nombre del archivo y de la comunidad como argumentos de la función.